# How to generate a splint log

Tags: c, logging, splint

I want generate, under Linux, a complete splint report file including also the date and the split tool version.
I tried with ">" to redirect the stdio split output to a file but inside the file I found only the split messages
To better explain, I run splint on main.c and on stdio the messages are :

```
**Splint 3.1.2 --- 20 Feb 2018
main.c: (in function main)
main.c:7:8: Variable c declared but not used
A variable is declared but never used. Use /*@unused@*/ in front of
declaration to suppress message. (Use -varuse to inhibit warning)
Finished checking --- 1 code warning**
```

now I run again the splint tool : splint main.c > report.txt

in the report.txt file I don't found  "**Splint 3.1.2 --- 20 Feb 2018" and "Finished checking --- 1 code warning**" but only the specifi splint messages.
How can redirect whole splint output into a file ?
Thanks

Comment: Did you try to redirect `stderr`, too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since these lines are output via `stderr`, redirect that into your log file, too.